# How do I close a JFrame that opened another frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I've a program that starts with a welcomeScreen JFrame, on which it has a JButton with the option of starting the game.. when I click that button, it opens the JFrame with my game however it does not close.. anyway of how to do this? I only know System.exit(0) and this closes everything..

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try: `jFrame.dispose();`

Answer (score 3):

> I've a program that starts with a welcomeScreen JFrame, on which it
>   has a JButton with the option of starting the game.. when I click that
>   button, it opens the JFrame with my game however it does not close..
>   anyway of how to do this? I only know System.exit(0) and this closes
>   everything..

- don't to create another `JFrame`
- use `CardLayout` with `JFrame.pack()`, after card is switched